# getting echo from batch script when background task ends

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this kind of batch file

```
start /b ruby script.rb && echo done
...
```

However, it write 'done' immediately after i run the batch file, which is incorrect, as the script took about 5 mins.

So, how to echo done only after the bg task succesfully end?

thank you!

note: I think that && operator work this way if it is not used in batch file nor in usage to run bg task.

Comment: why don't you check if your script is still running or not. and after checking that do echo.

Comment: i know that my script is not running anymore, also I have and echo from my script that it ends, but the echo from batch file is not working desired way. Also, there are many functions that does not return 'i have ended' echo when they ends, so i have to check it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start "" /b cmd /c "ruby script.rb && echo done"
```

Without the quotes the conditional execution command is seen as the continuation of the `start` command instead of continuation of the `ruby` command.

As the `&&` is an operator handled by `cmd` we need to start a new instance.

The `""` at the start are needed as the first quoted argument to `start` is handled as a window title.

note: `&&` is an conditional execution operator. If the previous command does not generate an error then the following command is executed. In this case with the process running in background, *probably*, `&`, the command concatenation operator, should be used to know that the script ended.